# Size of basketball used by 7th/8th grade boys per state

Tags: basketball

I can't find a resource to answer this question.  Looking for the size of the basketball used by boys in the 7th/8th grade by state.

**28.5**
Ohio

**29.5**
Kentucky
West Virginia
Indiana
Michigan

Comment: I have refereed in a few states and I have never heard of a junior high grade using a 28.5" ball.   There is a good chance you will have a 6'0"ish height player on a good 7th grade team.   That would be ridiculous using a kids ball.   Also the question is bad.   This is because NFHS and high school rules in general are not subject to non-high school basketball.   The specific league you play in notes that it will choose to play by a standard and could even say it plays by NFHS but wants a certain size ball used.   The league can do whatever it wants - there is no body for 7th grade bball.

Comment: Question is not bad as most middle school teams follow the HS rules with a few exceptions.  As they do in states that surround me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very much a partial answer; in Kansas we use the 28.5 for middle school boys.  I should know; as a middle school coach I've got something like twenty of the little things.

Comment: Over 3 years later, literally the first place that I've heard to use the 28.5 outside of Ohio.

Answer (score 2):

Any programs that follow the [US Amateur Basketball National Rules](https://usamateurbasketball.com/national-rules):

> The National High School Federation Rules and Regulations (NHSF) will apply to all US Amateur Basketball games with the following exceptions.
> ...
>
> - Middle and High School (Grades 7 thru 12) will consist of two sixteen minute halves and will use a regulation size basketball (intermediate size ball for Women).
> - Grades 3 thru 6 will consist of two fourteen minute halves and will use the 28.5 intermediate size ball.

Answer (score 0):

[Ebay listing](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Spalding-TF-1000-Legacy-Indoor-Basketball-OFFICIAL-29-5-/192014907898) says the 28.5" Spalding-1000 is the official size for women and boys 12 and under.

Although I'm having trouble finding records for many states, so far I've found:

Alabama & Alaska use NFHS rules, but don't specify ball size for Junior High. Probably 29.5".

**29.5**
[Arizona](http://image.aausports.org/handbooks/boys_basketball/2017_Handbook_11_07_16.pdf)

Comment: This is not accurate at all.  I've been doing my research.  So far, every state I've gotten info from is 29.5 except Ohio.  Updating post momentarily.

Comment: There is nothing that governs 7th/8th grade basketball in the US.   Each league can do whatever it wants (I am sure 99% use 29.5" at these ages as this size ball is usually introduced in 4th-5th grade)